# C++ OpenCV on Windows - cv::imshow() freezes and never returns but works fine on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, ubuntu, cross-platform

I have written an API which gets images, and wanted to test it. For this, I wrote a simple test harness using openCV which works fine on linux (Ubuntu 20 LTS), displaying the images as a video. On windows however, the openCV `cv::imshow()` window appears but never shows an image, while displaying the "Not Responding" warning in the title bar of the window (freezing).

I created this MVE which seems to fail in the exact same manner on Windows while also working on Ubuntu:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdint>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

void stream_callback(uint8_t* img_buffer){
    cv::Mat frame(1200, 1920, CV_8UC1, img_buffer);
    cv::imshow("Video Stream", frame);
    cv::waitKey(1);
    return;
}

void m_dummy_stream_recv_thread(){
  uint8_t* img_dat = new uint8_t[1920 * 1200];
  int width = 1920;
  int height = 1200;
  int shift = 0;

  while (true){
    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++){
      img_dat[i] = shift + i % 255;
    }
    
    shift += 10;
    stream_callback(img_dat);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cv::namedWindow("Video Stream", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    std::thread stream_thread(m_dummy_stream_recv_thread);
    stream_thread.detach();

    while(1){}

    return 0;
}
```

On Ubuntu, I have openCV installed via apt and compile with:

```
g++ ./openCV/imshow_freeze/main.cpp -o ocvtest -I/usr/include/opencv4/ -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -pthread
```

On Windows, I am using MSYS2 with the MinGW-64 toolchain and openCV installed via pacman for MSYS2, compiled with:

```
g++ ./openCV/imshow_freeze/main.cpp -o ocvtest -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/opencv4 -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core
```

Among a number of tweaks in how I generate/store/pass the data, I have also tried various timings for `cv::waitkey()` but with how simple this is, I am not sure what else to try.

I have also tried debugging, and it seems the data is reaching the `callback()` function just fine, but when continually stepping into the `cv::imshow()` call, it bounces to a few functions before the thread seemingly ends in this section of `basic_string.h` (I think the thread is dying because of an uncaught exception, but the main thread continues, does that seem correct? It is somewhat confusing because I see many more threads get created in GDB, but I am not sure how to read/interpret/debug multiple threads, especially ones that I'm assuming are launched by CV?):

```
basic_string.h:623 (for me)
{
    // NB: Not required, but considered best practice.
    if (__s == 0 && __n > 0)
      std::__throw_logic_error(__N("basic_string: "
                       "construction from null is not valid"));
    _M_construct(__s, __s + __n, std::forward_iterator_tag());
}
```

Im hoping someone can point out what I might be doing wrong if anything, or what I could do so that something similar to this could work on both Windows under MSYS2 and Ubuntu if it's just a slight difference in the library for the two platforms.

As an aside, while it is moderately different, I do know that the openCV on my windows/MSYS2 setup CAN work, as this simpler implementation does work and display my images as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

void show_image(uint8_t* img_buffer){
  cv::Mat frame(1200, 1920, CV_8UC1, img_buffer);
  cv::imshow("Video Stream", frame);
  cv::waitKey(1);
  return;
}

bool read_next_frame(uint8_t* image_data, int* width, int* height){
  int w = *width = 1920;
  int h = *height = 1200;
  static int shift = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < w * h; ++i){
    image_data[i] = shift + i % 255;
  }
  shift += 10;
  return true;
}

void displayVideoStream(){
    // Create a window to display the video stream
  cv::namedWindow("Video Stream", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

  // Assume you have a function 'read_next_frame()' to get the next frame as uint8_t* image_data, and its width and height.
  // Replace this loop with your video stream loop:
  uint8_t* image_data = new uint8_t[1920 * 1200];
  int width;
  int height;
  while (read_next_frame(image_data, &width, &height)){
      // Create a cv::Mat object from the image data
    show_image(image_data);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  displayVideoStream();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: threading breaks GUIs, specifically Win32 GUI, when you call GUI functions from multiple threads. all the gui stuff must be called from the same thread, which should be the main thread (the thread that's there before you create any) -- your simpler example works because it doesn't use any extra threads. whatever else is different between those two, "threading" should be in your list of suspects. -- that's not a [mre]. too much going on. you can strip that down to no sleeping, no video stream, just one spawned thread. the crux of a MRE is that everything in it is vital to reproducing the issue.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz You're right about my 'MRE', I'll edit it. It grew to resemble my actual code too much because I couldn't reproduce the issue and kept adding things, until I realized I was compiling the wrong file, quite silly of me. ----- That being said, do you have any recommendations for my desired functionality (a thread which serves images to another thread doing GUI)? I wanted to avoid the synchronization/overhead of having the callback copy to the main thread or using shared memory, I've seen other APIs do something similar to this but maybe they're doing their callbacks different?

Comment: if you want to stick with opencv for the imshow, you'll have to funnel all the imshow stuff through a single thread. use queues or other sync primitives for that. -- in a GUI with a proper GUI toolkit, everything (events/signals/data) is passed around between threads anyway, and concurrent access is either guarded, or there is no concurrent access and it's all turned into events that go in an event queue that's processed by the event loop.

Comment: From my experience, in windows (at least msvc) calling cv::namedWindow in the main thread and using cv::imshow in additional threads works well (as long as data access is guarded).

Comment: @DouglasB The issue is now reproducible. Moving `cv::namedWindow("Video Stream", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);` to `m_dummy_stream_recv_thread()` function (before the loop) solves the issue.

Comment: @Rotem unfortunately that is not an option in my own full code, as `m_dummy_stream_recv_thread()` will be a private member function of a class I am creating for this API which will be distributed as a library. For now I am just copying the data to a global variable in the callback and signaling the main thread to update using condition variables, which is working if not slightly more complex